# Can we switch two virtual displays in parallel ? Montery, MissionControl

Tags: macos, desktop

When I work at my desk, I have an external display on top of my Mac. I have one application, let's say the *mainapp* on the external monitor. And another application, let's call it the *console* on the MacBook monitor. They are both in fullscreen and the *mainapp* is on top of the *console*.

```
+--------------------+
|     Main App       |
| (external monitor) |
|                    |
+--------------------+

  +---------------+
  |    Console    |
  |   (MacBook)   |
  |               |
  +---------------+
```

My issue is that, when I swipe from one display, the other one do not swipe too. However, I would like to swipe both on the same time.

Can we achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're both fullscreen, it cannot be done.

Each fullscreen Space is one screen & one screen only, no metter how you arrange your Spaces.
The only way round this is to use the apps maximised rather than fullscreen, then uncheck 'Displays have Separate Spaces in Mission Control Prefs.

[image]

This will now make your screens move as a pair - however, if you try to fullscreen any app, it will only use one of the screens, the other will remain black. As far as I know, there's no way around this limitation, hence the advice to maximise rather than fullscreen.